# Executing code in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a application that periodically (via an `NSTimer`) asks for the users location using `locationManager:startUpdatingLocation` I want the locationManager to run in the background so have entered "UIBackgroundModes = location" in the info.plist file.

My question is I am not seeing the results I expected, am I right in thinking that when I press the home button the application delegate calls "applicationDidEnterBackground" but although locationManager is allowed to continue my NSTimer is getting suspended (and as a consequence its not calling startUpdatingLocation to periodically query the devices position). Any ideas / solutions would be much appreciated ...

Gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All NSTimers are invalidated when entering the background. You need check via the CLLocationManager for any changes.

Just keep the startUpdateLocation running, you delegate will receive any major changes of the location.

When running in the background, you will only receive location changes based on cell towers.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify, my understanding is: there is no way to stop an application entering the background and there is no way whilst in the background to specify when the device should query its location. My issue is that I am writing a camping application to plot a hikers position (every 2 mins) in wilderness areas that will have very few cells towers.

Comment: No there is no way to disable the home button. The on major change will allow you to send a UILocalNotification, then you can tell the user that he must open the app to update his/her heading.

Comment: If you don't press the home button but just leave the application running to the phones dims the screen to power-saving and then locks the display ... is the application, NSTimers etc. still running. Just curious if there is some point where iOS suspends an application automatically, or does that only happen when "Home" is pressed?

Comment: Well I guess so, never tried that :S but the - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application will be called and net the - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application so I guess you will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for [-applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW20) you'll find that yes, your timers are invalidated. Furthermore, the iOS Application Programming Guide tells you exactly how to [track location from the background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6).

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of these options (but not the fact that NSTimers would stop working) My problem is that SLC does not generate locations with any regularity, particulary in a rural/wilderness area. The only other option is "Running Continuously" and thats not good for battery life.